Must one be a researcher at a university to become an author of a research paper?
Is it a requirement to be a researcher at a university or affiliated with an academic institution in order to be eligible to become an author of a research paper with a DOI, or can individuals who are not affiliated with any university or academic institution also contribute to academic publications that receive a DOI?

The DOI tends to go along with being published in a certain conference proceedings or journal, so if your article is accepted, then you'll get a DOI.  Most online portals I've used to submit work tend to assume you have an affiliation, so it might be a slight technical issue, but I would just contact the relevant programme chair or journal contact and ask them what to do in that case.

Don't we have a standard question about this?

Just to add to what everyone else is saying, sometimes a particular journal may only be open to submissions from academia. For example, journals that are specifically about special needs teaching may only accept articles from people with industry experience teaching people with special educational needs. This is the exception, rather than the rule.

I posted this same example a couple of weeks ago, but I'll repeat it here: the team that researched the failure of the launch pad during SpaceX's Starship Flight 1 flight test asked members of the public on Twitter to send in videos and photos as well as samples from the dust clouds. Those Twitter users are all listed as authors of the paper with their affiliation credited as "Independent Researcher". Many of them are just residents of the area. None of them are academic researchers.

It's some time ago but Einstein was working in public administration when he published his most important papers, until 1908.

No, you don't need to be a researcher at a university to be published. You need to be able to write publishable papers in a field as judged by editors and reviewers. That is the only requirement.
There are also researchers at other sorts of institutions, both governmental and commercial. I know several of these at places like IBM and Google, among others.
There are also "independent researchers" who develop the necessary talent and have the skill to both do meaningful research and write it up appropriately for others.
If you can satisfy reviewers with the quality of your work, it will probably be published, and probably receive a DOI. But only deal with reputable publishers if you want to be recognized.
While the above assumes that you mean "sole authorship", that isn't the only path. Collaborative work among several authors, even those with different (or no) affiliation is also possible.

Thank you so much!

Shayn from the Crossref (DOI registration agency) support team here.  Just noting that DOIs aren't a mark of legitimacy or quality.  They're just identifiers.  Whether a published research paper has a DOI or not is a decision made by the publisher.
There also a number of repositories and preprint servers (for example Zenodo, arXiv, bioRxiv, chemRxiv, Research Square, preprints.org, figshare, some dataverse instances, etc. ) that assign and register DOIs for preprints and datasets.  So, if you want the benefits of a persistent identifier, regardless of publication status, it's not hard to get one.  That alone just doesn't say anything meaningful about the quality of your work.

Hi Shayn,
Once, I asked a question in the Crossref community, and someone named Shayn helped me with the answer: https://community.crossref.org/t/can-a-sci-fi-book-have-a-doi/12493. If that's you, it's great to run into you here. Thanks again!
In my opinion, Buffy's answer best addressed my question, as it made it clear that you don't need to be a university employee to be an author of a scientific publication. From your response, I understood that a DOI is not an indicator of the quality of scientific work. Thanks for your contribution here!

Hi yes, that's me!  I'm glad your question about publishing as an independent scholar (not affiliated with a university) was answered.  I just wanted to add some extra context to try and clear up some common misconceptions about DOIs, where they come from, and what they signify.

The world is a very small place :) Thank you so much!

No, you don't need to be a researcher at a university to become an author of a research paper.
Here's an example. Note the affiliations cited - the lead author for example is from "Quantum Circuits Inc." which is a private company.

Thank you so much!
